# Postgres 8.4 -- connection refused (remote)

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to postgres and looking to set up a small environment here with it.

I've installed PostgreSQL 8.4 onto an ubuntu server, able to login to the postgres, submit commands, do queries, etc... however, I'm looking at using [pgAdminIII](http://www.pgadmin.org/) from my windows machine.

I've followed along with the instructions from the [ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL) and made the following two changes:

In `pg_hba.conf` I have added the line (using other IP information, which should be fine as it's tested elsewhere):

`host    all         all         10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0    trust`

in `postgresql.conf` I had originaly set `listen_address = 'localhost,10.0.0.1'`, but changed to `listen_address = '*'` out of frustration after reading [this guide](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.12/connect-error.html).

How should I configure my listen files here so that postgres isn't listening to `*` ?

Answer (score 2):

The 10.0.0.1 is the address of your client.  What you need to put into `listen_addresses` is an address on the server.  If you don't want to use `*`, then it should be the address of the server on the same network as the client.  In this case this would probably be some other 10.* address.  Check with `/sbin/ifconfig` or `ip addr list` what address that would be on your host.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just need to restart your Postgres server or reload the configuration, you can do it with:

```
pg_ctl -D \yourDBpath -o -i reload
```

Also the "-o -i" tells the Postgres server to activate tcp/ip connections.